# When are sequential field values important in Firestore index exemptions?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

> If you index a field that increases or decreases sequentially between
> documents in a collection, like a timestamp, then the maximum write
> rate to the collection is 500 writes per second. If you don't query
> based on the field with sequential values, you can exempt the field
> from indexing to bypass this limit.
>
> [Firestore index exemption best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#index_exemptions)

When does Firestore care if a field is changing sequentially versus simply changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timestamp is still sequential, it's just not consecutive. Same applies to alphabetical, and pretty much any reasonably predictably generated values.

Sequential data in the indexes is likely to be written in close physical proximity on the storage media too, which is the reason it causes a limit on write throughput.

Comment: You seem to think there's an active process that looks for these patterns. That is not the case. Firestore uses a hash function to map document to locations, and if the values are not randomly distributed, writes will not distribute evenly over those locations. That is what leads to the bottle neck.

Comment: "Why does Firestore care if a field value is sequential?" There's a physical limit to how much data can be written to a phyiscal location in a certain timeframe. Predictable values/keys often end up in the same physical location, so are more likely to hit such a physical limit. I've answered that multiple times in multiple ways at this point, so if this doesn't help, I hope that either it gets clearer if you reread, or that someone else can explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the *why* part of your question, the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/shard-timestamp) provides a great explanation:

> Cloud Firestore places lexicographically close index entries on the same tablet. If the index values in a tablet are too close together, such as for timestamp fields, Cloud Firestore cannot efficiently split the tablet into smaller tablets. This creates a hot spot where a single tablet receives too much traffic, and read and write operations to the hot spot become slower.